# How to find offset of st_link?

Tags: c

What number we have to add to the base address of struct stat to find the offset of st_nlink in fstat system call ?

Comment: Just curious: why do you need this?

Comment: *why do you need this?*  Indeed.  This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`offsetof()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html):

```
offsetof(struct stat, st_nlink)
```

Comment: but how i ll use this in assembly code ,using system call ?

Comment: Finding the offset of a member inside a structure has nothing at all to do with system calls. As for using "assembly code", why would you do that?